# rounded Imageview in android eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I rounded Image View but the picture of Image view not round?

I use eclipse and XML

What do I do?  see this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
userImage.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: RoundedBitmapDrawable not recogonized

Comment: Have you import the support libarary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your ImageView is that your ImageViews background is Rounded but the Image you set in your android:src="" is not rounded, thats why you are getting a Image like that

I was looking for a rounded ImageView too a few days ago and i found this to make any ImageView rounded without using any Library

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }

    Bitmap b = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP 
        && drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        ((VectorDrawable) drawable).draw(canvas);
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBitmap(b);
        drawable.draw(c);
    } 
    else {
        b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


    return output;
}
   }
```

But if you want to use a Library check this out https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Answer (score 0):

Use  image as .png format then only image background transparent and image show inside the round.